# Is there a way i can trigger savepoint programmatically or via REST API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have enabled checkpoint which gets triggered at regular interval and being pushed to S3 bucket.

Can I trigger savepoint programmatically or via REST endpoint, so that save point will be triggered and saved to S3 using `state.savepoints.dir` ?

Purpose of this savepoint is to maintain a known stable state and can be used to restore at later point of time.

Env:

```
flink version: 1.12.1
installation on: k8s
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following path in REST API to create savepoint `/jobs/:jobid/savepoints`. You will obviously need to know the id of the job You want to trigger savepoint for.
The request is a POST request with body:

```
{
 "cancel-job":[boolean to indicate if job should be stopped,
 "target-directory": [path in which savepoint should be kept
}
```

You can refer to the [docs] for more info.[1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/rest_api.html)